# Is there a way to overwrite the value that is stored on AWS Paremeter Store on Pyspark

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark

I was able to get the parameter from my AWS glue script

`ssm = boto3.client('ssm', region_name='us-east-1')`

`date = ssm.get_parameter(
    Name='/Test/Date',
    WithDecryption=True
)
print(date['Parameter']['Value'])`

but is it possible to overwrite the value on the parameter store "/Test/Date" using pyspark syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to delete and put a new parameter using the client u have used above. U can write it the same way u would write anything in python using boto3 and use it in your spark script.There isn’t any separate pyspark syntax for such an activity.

Comment: By using AWS CLI: 
aws ssm put-parameter --name "/Test/Date" --value "2020-04-03 12:23:37" --type String --overwrite

I was able to overwrite the value on the "/Test/Date" parameter manually. I was trying to get the maximum timestamp that the AWS Glue have saved after ETL run finished. How to write the new date that was stored AWS Glue and use the put-parameter to store it to "/Test/Date" parameter store. How to link the AWS Glue with AWS CLI?

Comment: You need to use boto3 as mentioned. U can use the boto3 module in glue

Comment: was now able to use boto3 in glue to put parameter in parameter store. Thanks for the advise Emerson